# How to specify count for module inside a composed module?

Tags: spring-xd

For example, I'd like to create a composed module as 'myprocessor':

```
xd> module compose myprocessor --definition "processor1 | processor2 | processor3".
```

In addition, I'd also like to make the number of processor1, processor2 and processor3 be 4:2:1 in the composed module and all the communication between them are in-process.

How can I achieve it? Can I specify it during creation using command like:

```
xd> module compose myprocessor --definition "processor1 --count=4| processor2 --count=2| processor3 --count=1"
```

or during deployment?

Thanks,

Simon

Answer (score 1):

No; that's not possible. A composed module is a single module (a black box) with the component modules being hard-wired together.

But since you have "reducing" counts, simply set the count to 4 when using the composed module. What are you trying to achieve using fewer processor2/3 than 1 ?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Using 'Reducing' counts is just an example, what I want to achieve is:  1. Deploy all the modules in the composed module in- process to avoid extra network hop from using a data bus like RabbitMQ.  2. Can specify the count/parallelism of each module in the composed module so that they have matching processing bandwidth with each other.

Comment: As I said "black box". If your performance needs require `n` of processor `x`, then use `n` of the composed module. Composed modules are hard-wired internally; to achieve what you want would require additional complexity (threading) within the composed module. You can always achieve what you want by using an `ExecutorChannel` internally within the module - i.e. specify the `input` channel with a `dispatcher` and a `task-executor` (thread pool).